# IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage stuck in multithreading environment

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I launch the IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage method for each item in a folder in a number of background threads. The code looks like that:

```
HRESULT GetImage(IShellItemImageFactory* pImgFactory,
                 SIZE Size, COLORREF BkColor, HBITMAP *phbm)
{
    if (pImgFactory == 0 || phbm == 0)
        return E_POINTER;
    *phbm = 0;

    HBITMAP hBmp = 0;
    HRESULT hr = pImgFactory->GetImage(Size, SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK, &hBmp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && hBmp)
    {
        *phbm = CPicture::StretchBitmap(hBmp, Size, BkColor);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Sometimes I have the all 16 threads stuck inside call to pImgFactory->GetImage for different items. They all stuck in one and the same place, which could be seen in the provided stack. I checked that different threads process different items. What can be a cause of such strange phenomenon?
[image]
EDIT:
After David Heffernan's response I realized that the IShellItemImageFactory interface itself can be not thread safe. Our threading subsystem automatically initializes each thread as STA (by the call to CoInitialize(0) function). But may be, for IShellItemImageFactory I need MTA threads. Is there a way to discover the IShellItemImageFactory's coclass CLSID, in order to find in the Registry its threading requirements?

EDIT2:
Probably, our threading mechanism somehow related to the problem. In this specific case we use an engine that we call "Job Queue". It is non-blocking FIFO queue, which elements describe a job. The description contains pointers to job's algorithm and job's data. Typically (but not necessary) the main thread puts jobs to the queue. A free thread from thread pool may get element from the queue and perform the job. This mechanism worked well for us already a couple of years. But may be, it somehow affects icon extraction. May be, I wasn't sufficiently exact in defining the icon extracting algorithm and data. I don't know how can I determine it.

Comment: Perhaps your code is not threadsafe. Perhaps you didn't initialise COM. Perhaps something else is wrong. You didn't show a MCVE.

Comment: i can assume that you wait on Mutant - `\BaseNamedObjects\C::Users:<user name>:AppData:Local:Microsoft:Windows:Explorer:thumbcache_idx.db!rwWriterMutex` . if this is really mutant - we can look KMUTANT.OwnerThread - determinate which thread hold it, and what he doing. but for this need have good debugger and skills

Comment: @RbMm: A good debugger provides automatic deadlock support (like WinDbg's [!locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563980.aspx) command). (On a personal note: Your contributions would be a lot more helpful, if you didn't try to make everyone except for yourself look like an idiot.)

Comment: @IInspectable !locks is good but not always help. by thread id we can got PETHREAD pointer, view on which object thread wait (by looking KWAIT_BLOCK). if this say a KEVENT - in general impossible say why it in not signaled state, who and where must set it. but in this is mutant - exist OwnerThread, which we can view. get it pid/tid. attach to process and look where he is wait. why not call ReleaseMutex. this how be i research this lock.

Comment: thumbcache.dll usual use several named mutant(mutex) for synchronize access to cache. so i guess mutant lock in this case. when `!locks` primary work for critical sections in user mode..

Comment: @David Heffernan, my own thread's code doesn't need synchronization, except of the call to IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage. And our threading subsystem automatically initializes each thread as STA (by the call to CoInitialize(0) function). But may be, for IShellItemImageFactory I need MTA threads. How can I find the IShellItemImageFactory's threading requirements?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Have you examined the example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940383(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ilia - IShellItemImageFactory implemented by same object as IShellItem[2] and it can run in any aptament (STA, MAINSTA, MTA, NA - i view this at object creation time ) and from your stack trace clear visible that you hang not in `CRITICAL_SECTION` (`WaitForSingleObjectEx` cannot be called from critical section code). i still almost sure that your problem with some mutex, and thread which hold it, hang

Comment: @RbMm, Yes, but it is a mutex used proprietarily by IShellItemImageFactory, how can I affect it? Except of the system-launched threads, there are only image extracting threads, which are all blocked, a couple of our internal service threads that have no relation to the matter, and the main thread, which is alive and shows empty images. I simply do not know where to search...

Comment: @Ilia - mutext have `OwnerThread` i be got mutant pointer, look this field value and then CLIENT_ID of this thread(pid/tid) finally attach debugger to process(pid) and look thread(tid) stack - where he wait. i not say that you affect it. hard to say in what error at this point.

Comment: @Ilia - so search need for thread which owner of mutex and what he doing - guess that he also wait on something

Comment: @RbMm, OK, I experimentally found how to get a pointer to unknown mutex in debugger: go to disassembly and look at the content of rdi register. But how can I find values of the fields you mentioned without knowing of the exact mutex layout? Is its structure described somewhere? I simply do not know, and would be grateful if you'll teach me...

Comment: @Ilia - this is `struct _KMUTANT` can be found in `wdm.h` (https://github.com/alexhenrie/wine/blob/master/include/ddk/wdm.h) from any WDK build. this is kernel mode memory - you looking in kernel debugger ?

Comment: @RbMm, No, I use the ordinary user-mode debugger for ordinary user-mode application. I have no experience in Windows driver development. So I need to install WDK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128387/discussion-between-rbmm-and-ilia).

Comment: @Ilia RbMm is a keen reverse engineer. Not sure that's what you need. Surely you need to know the high level contract not some gory low level implementation specific details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - here not question in reverse engineer, but in debugging - why is deadlock ? i cannot reproduce this deadlock by self (i tried without success) but understand that here not `CRITICAL_SECTION` hang (so `!locks` not help) but probably wait on mutex. if this is true - need looking for mutex owner thread, why he not release mutex. obviously wait on some another object . understand on what wait mutex owner can very help with understand entirely problem and fix it. i dont know are/how with Windbg we can determinate mutex owner, however with my private debugger this is easy possible

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you for help. Please see the answer.

Comment: @RbMm, thank you for help. Please see the answer.

Comment: @Ilia - thank. really i not helped you ), only assume that here mutex wait

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon is not really a deadlock. It happens when extracting images of subfolders in a folder, which was not still cached by the Windows. Suppose there is a folder F with 20 subfolders F1,F2,...,F20, each of which contains 20+ other subfolders and files. If folder F is not cached, extraction of 20 images of its subfolders may take 15 - 25 min (on my Win10 8-core computer). After the all images were once extracted, repeated requests for images in that folder F are performed fast.